# Insert primefaces dataTable rows based on p:inputText fields

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, javabeans

I would like a sugestion how implement this case. (using jsf 2.0 and primefaces 3.5)

- Have about 10 primefaces inputTexts
- Have one primefaces dataTable
- Have an entity named Contact with 10 properties like (name,description,etc...)
- How the best way to add rows in dataTable after typing in the inputTexts and clicking on button. ? ***(I cant persist data on DB. Only add the typed new data in the dataTable new row)***

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so here's what you'd do (10 times) to get your result :

Start with specifying whichever entity bean you desire, we'll stay generic here to make this useful for as many good souls :

```
package pack;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Entity {

    private String entityProperty ;

    public String getEntityProperty() {
        return entityProperty;
    }

    public void setEntityProperty(String entityProperty) {
        this.entityProperty = entityProperty;
    }


    public Entity(String e) {
        this.entityProperty = e ;
    }
}
```

You'll have then to use this `Entity` in a bean (which I called `Bean`). We do that to fill a list which the `dataTable` we'll iterate to create its rows. Here's the bean :

```
    package pack ;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {
    private String property ;
    private ArrayList<Entity> list ;

    public ArrayList<Entity> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<Entity> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public Bean() {
        list = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    }

    public void showInDataTable(){
        list.add(new Entity(property));
    }

}
```

Lastly, we come to the presentation page, a tour on [primefaces site](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf) usually gives you an idea about what to use and how :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>StackOverflow</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:inputText value="#{bean.property}" />
            <p:commandButton value="show in dataTable" action="#{bean.showInDataTable}" update="dataTable"/>
            <p:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{bean.list}" var="o">
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{o.entityProperty}" /> 
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

So you adapt this to your needs, it should flow nicely once you determine which properties your `Entity` equivalent must handle (that's to say, in your case, 9 more properties for the bean and for the entity and an adjusted constructor for those).

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you so much @Gloserio for helping me with this issue to me. Thats a clean and generic code. thank you again...

Comment: Glad it serves you well :).

Answer (score 0):

Try following

- Make **List** of **Contact** class as table value.
- In the **actionListener** method of commandButton,  create **new Contact class** and set it's property with **appropriate inputText**.
- **Append** that newly created object to List
- In commandButton : **process** inputTexts, **update** Datatable

Which will not required to store intermediate result into database

Comment: Thanks for the info @Jitesh. It will be useful to me in the future.